# Swift: How a Button Can Perform a Sequence

Tags: ios, swift

How can a button unhid textfields each time its pressed and then after 4 times of being pressed the button becomes inactive? Here is my code so far. Thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit

class AddNewGameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Player1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Player2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Player3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Player4: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        Player1.hidden = true
        Player2.hidden = true
        Player3.hidden = true
        Player4.hidden = true



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func addPlayer(sender: UIButton) {
        sender.enabled = false

        Player1.hidden = false
        Player2.hidden = false
        Player3.hidden = false
        Player4.hidden = false


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `@IBOutlet`s to a `@IBOutlet Collection`like this :

```
@IBOutlet var players: [UITextField]!
```

then connect each `textfield` to it `Player1`->`Player2`-> `Player3`->`Player4`

finally in the btn action :

```
for textField in players {

    if textField.hidden {
        textField.hidden = false
        if textField == players.last {
            sender.enabled = false
        }
        break
    }

}
```

### update

you can hide all them with `players.forEach {$0.hidden = true}` in `viewDidload`
or hide them in xib/storyboard.

### connect image :

[image]

Comment: It did not work. Now all the textfield show even if i have them hidden.

Comment: how do I connect the textfields to the @IBOutlet Collection?

Comment: @DoughnutMan check it i post a image

Comment: do you know how I could disable the button after all four textfields are unhidden?

Comment: @DoughnutMan in the for loop , add `if textField == players.last { // set the btn hidden  }`

Comment: @DoughnutMan i edited the answer ,it works in well in my project